# jQuery contextMenu checkbox selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, contextmenu

i am using contexMenu by SWIS and i don't know how can i change the selected vale from a checkbox. 
i have this code:

```
function isOk(){
    return false;
}

$.contextMenu({
    selector: "td[name*='someSelector']", 
    callback: function(key, options) {
        var m = "clicked: " + key + " id: "+ this.attr('id');
        window.console && console.log(m) || alert(m);
    },
    items: {
        "okOption": {
            name: "ok", 
            type: 'checkbox', 
            selected: function(){ return isOk(); }
        },
        "quit": {
            name: "Close Menu", 
            icon: function(){
                return 'context-menu-icon context-menu-icon-quit';
            }
        }
    }
});
```

But the checkbox is always true.

I don't know what is wrong or if the selected doesn't works with a function and only works with a true or false.

```js
function isOk(){
   return false;
  }
  
  $.contextMenu({
   selector: "[name*='someSelector']", 
   callback: function(key, options) {
    var m = "clicked: " + key + " id: "+ this.attr('id');
    window.console && console.log(m) || alert(m);
   },
   items: {
    "okOption": {
     name: "ok", 
     type: 'checkbox', 
     selected: {function(){ return isOk(); }}
    },
    "quit": {name: "Close Menu", icon: function(){
     return 'context-menu-icon context-menu-icon-quit';
     }
    }
   }
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://swisnl.github.io/jQuery-contextMenu/dist/jquery.contextMenu.js"></script>
<script src="https://swisnl.github.io/jQuery-contextMenu/js/theme.js"></script>
<link href="https://swisnl.github.io/jQuery-contextMenu/dist/jquery.contextMenu.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<span name="someSelector"> ClickRightHere</span>
```

Comment: it'd be good to have the HTML, and even better if you post everything in a Stackoverflow code snippet! :)

Comment: Code snippet published. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally i solved using a event: 
Here the snippet with the solution for future people consult and solve it.

```js
function isOk() {
  return false;
}

$.contextMenu({
  selector: "[name*='someSelector']",
  callback: function(key, options) {
    var m = "clicked: " + key + " id: " + this.attr('id');
    window.console && console.log(m) || alert(m);
  },
  items: {
    "okOption": {
      name: "ok",
      type: 'checkbox'
    },
    "quit": {
      name: "Close Menu",
      icon: function() {
        return 'context-menu-icon context-menu-icon-quit';
      }
    }
  },
  events: {
    show: function(opt) {
      // this is the trigger element
      var $this = this;
      // import states from data store 
      $this.data().okOption = isOk();

      $.contextMenu.setInputValues(opt, $this.data());
      // this basically fills the input commands from an object
      // like {name: "foo", yesno: true, radio: "3", &hellip;}
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://swisnl.github.io/jQuery-contextMenu/dist/jquery.contextMenu.js"></script>
<script src="https://swisnl.github.io/jQuery-contextMenu/js/theme.js"></script>
<link href="https://swisnl.github.io/jQuery-contextMenu/dist/jquery.contextMenu.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<span name="someSelector"> ClickRightHere</span>
```

Comment: You can safely remove the `selected: {function(){ return isOk(); }}` part - it is of no use anymore.

Comment: Yes, thanks, it's true. Answer edited with the change.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use a function for the `selected` option. The [documentation](https://swisnl.github.io/jQuery-contextMenu/docs/items.html) says:

> selected: string or boolean

So you could use a variable like this:

```
var myFlag = false;

$.contextMenu({
    ...
    items: {
        "okOption": {
            name: "ok", 
            type: 'checkbox', 
            selected: myFlag
        },
    ...
```

Comment: yes, i thought use these but, i need to check when the right button click, and in these way only check when the page is loaded.